# Java Post Request to a Django Server --> 403 error code

Tags: java, django, cookies

Im pretty new to Java and I got a little Project as a learning task.
The first part was pretty easy, but now Im stuck.

I want to get some informations of a website via post request in Java.
But the tricky part is the crsf protection and I have no idea how to handle it, because if I try to make a POST request, I get the error code:
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://v1stats.desy.de:8080

I was told that I have to get the csrf-token via get Request and use this token for the post request, to tell the protecting system that Im not a roboter.

So I did this :

```
URL url = new URL(http://v1stats.desy.de:8080);
        try {

                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

                for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
                }

                token = map.get("Set-Cookie").toString();
                token = (String) token.subSequence(1, token.indexOf(";"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The result is :

```
X-Frame-Options: [SAMEORIGIN]
null: [HTTP/1.0 200 OK]
Server: [WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6]
Set-Cookie: [csrftoken=IzUo1yexx5scFLroXOIKAhf56wHDFUMg; expires=Thu, 24-Nov-2016 14:39:10 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/]
Vary: [Cookie]
Date: [Thu, 26 Nov 2015 14:39:10 GMT]
Content-Type: [text/html; charset=utf-8]
```

After that, I have the token.

My POST request code is this:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();

     params.put("start", "27/10/2015");
     params.put("end", "27/10/2015");
     params.put("room", "Basketballfeld");
     params.put("organizer", "");
     params.put("eventname", "");
     params.put("description", "");

     StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
     for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
         if (postData.length() != 0) 
             postData.append('&');
         postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=");           
         postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
     }

     System.out.println(postData);
     byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

     Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

The postData locks like this:

```
start=27%2F10%2F2015&end=27%2F10%2F2015&room=Basketballfeld&organizer=&eventname=&description=
```

Can anybody tell me what I have to do, to send the crsf token with the request to make sure, that the Django server response with the data I want?
Or am I completely wrong with what Im doing?

I searched a lot in the Internet, but Im not able to find a solution ;-(

(for sure because I don't have the know how and I don't exactly know what to search for)
Thanks for the Help!